# android - storing image in internal storage

Tags: android, file-io, storage, internal

I an trying to store images downloaded from web to internal storage. I am refer following solution [android - storing image cache in internal memory and reusing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204087/android-storing-image-cache-in-internal-memory-and-reusing-it?rq=1)

but still i am getting exception :

```
07-19 12:05:47.729: E/AndroidRuntime(341): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /data/data/com.yellow.activity/files/-1717792749 contains a path separator
```

How to load image from filepath :
   here is my code . **image** is an arraylist of URLs.

```
File fileWithinMyDir = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();
for(int i=0; i<image.size();i++){
                String filename = String.valueOf(image.get(i).hashCode());
                String urlString = image.get(i);
                String PATH = fileWithinMyDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/" +filename;
                infoLog(PATH);
                DownloadFromUrl(PATH, urlString);
                img_path.add(PATH);
        }


 private void DownloadFromUrl(String fileName, String urlStr) 
       {
          try 
          {
           URL url = new URL(urlStr);
           File file = new File(fileName);
           URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
           InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
           BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
           ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
           int current = 0;
           while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) 
           {
            baf.append((byte) current);
           }

           FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file,true);
           fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
           fos.close();
           infoLog("going  ryt....");
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            infoLog("download  "+ e.getMessage());
        }
      }
```

how to load image to  imageView? I tried.

```
        File filePath = getFileStreamPath(img_path.get(i));
        imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(filePath.toString()));
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: please add your urlStr String here..??? mean what you pass in that method.

Comment: What path you get in this fileWithinMyDir.getAbsolutePath()

Comment: path i m getting is /data/data/com.yellow.activity/files/-1718716270

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. 
    Replace following code

```
File filePath = getFileStreamPath(img_path.get(i)); 
imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(filePath.toString()));
```

with

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(img_path.get(i)));
```

Answer (score 1):

To save into internal memory...

```
   File fileWithinMyDir = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir();  
    try 
          {
              StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
              .permitAll().build();
          StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
           URL url = new URL("http://t2.gstatic.com  /images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQjZgUffqqe2mKKb5VOrDNd-ZxD7sJOU7WAHlFAy6PLbtXpyQZYdw");
           File file = new File( fileWithinMyDir.getAbsolutePath()  + "/" +"sun.jpg");
           URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
           InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
           BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
           ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
           int current = 0;
           while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) 
           {
            baf.append((byte) current);
           }

           FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
           fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
           fos.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            Log.e("download", e.getMessage());
        }
```

To load image from internal memory..

```
 StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
          .permitAll().build();
           StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
          mImgView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mImgView1); 

          Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileWithinMyDir.getAbsolutePath()  + "/" +"sunn"+".file extension");
          mImgView1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

This is for newer android's that show error due to " android.os.networkonmainthreadexception"

u can also use AsyncTask if u want to solve the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
String PATH = fileWithinMyDir.getAbsolutePath() + filename;
```

Comment: Still getting exception tht java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File /data/data/com.yellow.activity/files-1717792749 contains a path separator